# mysql howto mysql_fech_array and mysql query into array

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to do this in mysql?

2 tables

```
Hotel
id   name
1   Hotel 1


Pickup
id_hotel pickup_name pickup_time
1         Hotel_1a      09:20
1         Hotel_1b      14:20
```

When I make a JOIN it throws me 2 rows.

```
id  name    id_hotel pickup_name pickup_time
1  Hotel 1     1       Hotel_1a      09:20
2  Hotel 1     1       Hotel_2a      14:20
```

And when I make the mysql_fetch_array it makes me something like that:

```
[0] => { id=>1, name=>Hotel 1,id_hotel=>1, pickup_name=>Hotel_1a, pickup_time=>09:20}
[1] => { id=>1, name=>Hotel 1,id_hotel=>1, pickup_name=>Hotel_1b, pickup_time=>14:20}
```

I was wondering if I can do with an array.

Something like that:

```
[0] => { id=>1, 
         name=>Hotel 1,
         id_hotel=>1, 
         pickup_name=>Hotel_1a, 
         pickup_time=>array{
                            [0]=>09:20
                            [1]=>14:20
                      }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done with MySQL alone.

You have three ways of going about it:

1. Query the first table & then build the `pickup_time` field by querying the second table
2. Use the JOIN like you are doing now & build the array from the results of the JOIN
3. Use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)

#1 Is the simplest without abstraction, but will be the least efficient if you have a lot records to search through in both tables.

#2 Is possibly the most efficient as processing a couple of loops in PHP is faster than performing I/O to the database

#3 Is more complex because you'll have to learn the ORM, but it'll lead to more maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

No. You've got two records.
You need manually build the array.

Loop through the records and begin an new arrayindex by chanhing the ID.

Use order by-clause in the query

```
SELECT .... order by id
```

In PHP:

```
$myArray = null;
$index   = -1;
$lastID  = null;
//Loop
    if( $record[ 'id' ] !== $lastId ){
        $lastID = $record['id'];
        $index++;
        $myArray[ $index ] [ 'id' ]       = $record[ 'id' ];
        $myArray[ $index ] [ 'name' ]     = $record[ 'name' ];
        $myArray[ $index ] [ 'id_hotel' ] = $record[ 'id_hotel' ];
        //...
        $myArray[ $index ] ['pickup_time'] = array();
    }
    $myArray[ $index ] ['pickup_time'] = array_push( $record[ 'pickup_time' ] );
//loop-end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could GROUP CONCAT it and then use explode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Man, learn something new every day! Adding [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) with examples & explanation.